# Kafka Streams : Get count of events in time window

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have data stream as <string,string> events. I want to get count of events for 10 minutes time windows and output to another topic. Following is my code

```
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
streamsBuilder.stream("events")
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(10000)))
            .count()
            .toStream()
            .to("output");
```

but i get error

```
 ClassCastException while producing data to topic output. A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed / value type: java.lang.Long). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters (for example if using the DSL, `#to(String topic, Produced<K, V> produced)` with `Produced.keySerde(WindowedSerdes.timeWindowedSerdeFrom(String.class))`).
```

Comment: Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63643121/1701261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `windowedBy` plus `count()` is a key-value pair with type `<Windowed<String>, Long>` and thus you need to set a different serde in `to()` via `Produced` parameter. By default, the serdes from the config will be used that it seems you set to `StringSerde/StringSerde` and those obviously don't match the output topic key/value types.

Kafka Streams ships with built-in serdes for windowed types that you can get via `Serdes` factory class.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below can be tried

```
        .count()
        .toStream()
        .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key.key() + "@" + key.window().start() + "->" + key.window().end(), value))
        .to("output");
```